# How to stop a QThread from a PyQT5 GUI (Cannot use Flag)

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

The problem is how to stop (terminate|quit|exit) a QThread from the GUI in PyQT. The common and easy solution to this is to create a custom Flag, or to use requestInterruption() and isInterruptionRequested() flags. However, this would require changing the script inside the worker class (by adding these flags). In my case, I am not allowed to do so. In fact, inside of my worker class, I have to import another class that does all of the calculations and I have no control over it. I called this class `heavy_class_runs_gpu` just for the sake of example.

```py
import heavy_class_runs_gpu

import run_heavy_GPU_class
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, QTimer

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        heavy_class_runs_gpu() #----> I am not allowed to go and change the content of this class. So, I cannot insert any flag into this class. I can only import it.
        self.finished.emit()

class MyWidget(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = MyWidget()
    app.exec()
```

Again, I cannot use custom flags since I don't have a while-loop or for-loop to stop the thread. How should I stop or kill th thread in this case?

Comment: While QThread provides the static [`setTerminationEnabled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#setTerminationEnabled) function (which **must** be called from the running thread!), it also implicitly allows the usage of [`QThread.terminate()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate), which is normally discouraged. You may consider multiprocessing instead.

Comment: Thanks, so one can just write QThread.terminate()? how should I use it in the code?

Comment: What about *writing* it? You have a reference to the QThread instance (even if you overwrote an existing function of QObject, but that's another point), just call `terminate()` on it. Don't ask "can I do it?" before at least trying to do it (and properly read the related documentation and done some research about it).